# IconTheme no funciona en flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy intentando cambiar el color por defecto de todos los `Icon` de mi aplicación a negro. Para ello utilizo el siguiente código dentro de mi `MaterialApp`:

```
      theme: ThemeData(
    // Color scheme
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
      primary: Colors.white,
      secondary: Colors.black
    ),

    // Appbar
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),  
    ),
    

    // IconTheme
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),

    // Define the default font family.
    fontFamily: 'Wave',
));
```

Pero aunque defina su color por defecto en negro, los iconos siguen apareciendo blancos.
Ya intenté remover el colorScheme de el `ThemeData` y aun así no funciona.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás y dónde estás creando el/los iconos? Podría ser qué haya otro widget sobreescribiendo el ThemeData del icono que estás intentando crear de color negro.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de **iconTheme** utiliza **listTileTheme** si los iconos son de un **ListTile**

```
listTileTheme: const ListTileThemeData(
 iconColor: Colors.green
)
```